# Crystal Report deployment error

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i have C# program that works with Oracle 11g

when it works on my computer all works excellent

but when its run on the customer computer - the connection to Oracle work good

but when i try to run any Crystal-Report i get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 
CrystalDecisions.windows.forms.version = 10.5.3700.0.
culture = neutral.publicKey Token = 69fbea5521e1304 or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the specified
```

thank's for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the error, Looks like the DLL is missing. Did your installer include all relevent DLL's?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287928%28VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests the that the system couldn't find the libraries needed to run Crystal reports. Have you installed Crystal onto your customer's PCs?

Comment: Yes i installed Crystal to customer PC

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if an assembly hasn't been deployed to the client machine.  You will need to check your application dependencies, look at any referenced assemblies and ensure that they are present on you client machine.  The CrystalDecisions assembly on your machine might be installed in the GAC, you will need to copy it to you client deployment location.

You can use a tool to look at the [Fusion Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4(VS.71).aspx) to see which assemblies are loaded by your application, this log will show you any missing references.